# Contains on array of int

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I'm currently working (as a School Project) on a WebAPI for a conversation system.  It's basically a mailbox between two users.

When adding a new message, I would like to check if two users have already talked to each others.  Everything is currently stored as a variable in memory(it's only for school and can be improved later).

My model is something like this :

```
public class Conversation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int[] Users { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }

    public static List<Conversation> listeConversation = new List<Conversation>
    {
        new Conversation { 
            Id = 1, Users = new int[2] {1, 2}, Messages = new List<Message> {
                new Message { Id = 1, UserId = 1, Content = "Bonjour", Created = DateTime.Now},
                new Message { Id = 2, UserId = 2, Content = "Comment ça va ?", Created = DateTime.Now},
                new Message { Id = 3, UserId = 1, Content = "Très bien et toi ?", Created = DateTime.
        }
    };
}
```

In my method, I'm receiving sender and receiver id.   I would like to create a new method where I check if the Conversation List already contains one conversation bewteen these two users, but I don't really know how to do it.

I suppose that I have to use Contains, but I don't really know how to use it with arrays. I tried something like this:

```
private Conversation getConversationFromUsers(int[] users)
{
     Conversation.listeConversation.Where(c => c.Users.Contains(users));
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Do you want any conversation between just those users or any conversation where those two users participated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you need something like this?

```
Conversation.listeConversation.Where(c => c.Users.Contains(users[0]) && c => c.Users.Contains(users[1]);
```

**Update:** For more than two matches use something like this:

```
Conversation.listeConversation.Where(c => c.Users.Intersect(users).Count() > 2)
```

Comment: It work, but I thought I could find an easiest way to do it, without using two conditions. What if I've to search with more users, 3, 4 or 10 ?

Comment: What about the case where all array elements the same but in a different order? Maybe you van use 'Where(c => c.Users.All(u => users.Contains(u)) && users.All(u => c.Users.Contains(u)))'

Comment: Thanks, just changed the "2" by "users.Count()", thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `LINQ Intersect()` method:

```
var foundConversations = Conversation.listeConversation.Where(c => c.Users.Intersect(users).Count() >= users.Lenght).ToList();
```

It should work with any length array of users.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `HashSet<int>` to store the users whose conversations you want to find. This gives you access to the `SetEquals()` method, which tests for set equality which is what you are looking for.

```
private Conversation getConversationFromUsers(int[] users)
{
    var set = new HashSet<int>(users);
    return Conversation.listeConversation.FirstOrDefault(c => users.SetEquals(c.Users));
}
```